# Microsoft Access Linked File

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having a problem with a linked Excel file to an Access database.  I actually have seven linked files and six of them perform flawlessly.  One of them is constantly giving me fits.

When I run the query, it will often not work.  It gives me the error: *"You cannot record your changes because a value you entered violates the setting defined for this table or list (for example, a value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum).  Correct the error and try again."*

If I try again, the same error message pops up.

Interestingly, if I go into the query, put my cursor at the end of the query text, press the space bar, save, exit and run it again - IT WORKS!

Anyone else have this problem and know how to fix it?

```
SELECT CSTR(r.[Batch]) AS Batch, CSTR(r.[Material]) AS Material, CSTR(r.
[Order]) AS [Order], CSTR(r.[UD]) AS UD, CSTR(r.[Short text]) AS [Short 
text], CSTR(r.[End date1]) AS [End date1], CSTR(r.[Work ctr]) AS [Work ctr] 
INTO TEMP_RESULTS_NON_UD

FROM Results_NonUD AS r

WHERE r.Batch Is Not Null And r.Order Is Not Null And r.[End date1] Is Not 
Null;
```

So far I've tried the following:

- Remove all unnecessary columns from the spreadsheet
- Cast everything as text
- Remove any data that might trigger an error
- Re-linked the spreadsheet

Nothing is working!

Thanks in advance,
Jim

Comment: I think the error is somewhere in the table definition of `TEMP_RESULTS_NON_UD`. Try deleting that table and rerunning the query.

Comment: It actually deletes the table beforehand.  It's a "Make-Table" query - Access deletes the table, then recreates it according to the query.

Comment: Then please share the full code (including the code that deletes the table)

Comment: The posted query above is the full 'code.'  It is a function of Access to delete the table first when running a "Make Table" query.  (The Make Table query can be seen in the SQL part "INTO TEMP_RESULTS_NON_UD" (above).

Comment: An `SELECT ... INTO` doesn't fully delete the table when executed through the normal interface (it leaves stuff like constraints and relationships intact), and requires the table to be deleted when executed through VBA (except when using the DoCmd object, then behavior is the same as through the interface). Your information is invalid.

Comment: Did some more digging, the `SELECT ... INTO` not always fully deleting actually is fixed in Access 2016, but in Access 2010 it might still be the problem (don't know if it got patched there).

Comment: Ahhhh!  That would make sense - and actually your comment reminded me that I'm actually executing the query with a DoCmd but the problem exists in VBA as well as when manually executing the query.  Our company is moving to Office 365 here shortly so hopefully the move to the upgraded Access will help.  Until then I guess I'll just do my work-around.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: My advice: even if you get an updated office, move to `CurrentDb.Execute` or `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery").Execute`. `DoCmd` is useful for executing commands you'd normally run through the GUI, those other approaches use the database engine more directly. You will have to manually do the delete, though, cause those won't do it for you, but you won't have to do the weird `DoCmd.Setwarnings` stuff